# How to remove child entities when saving attached entity with EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Repository using EF Core. In the below scenario I first fetch an entity along with a related child collection. I then remove all the children and add a new child and also update one property on the parent entity.

After saving the property on the parent is update, the new child entity is added but all the original child entities are still in the database.

How can I get EF to track the removed child entities as deleted?

```
class Repository
{
    public Parent GetParent(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new LocalDbContext())
        {
            return db.Parents.Include(item => item.Images).FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateParent(Parent parent)
    {
        using (var db = new LocalDbContext())
        {
            var entry = db.Parents.Attach(parent);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}


var instance = new LocalDbContext();
var repository = new Repository();
var parent = repository.GetParent(123);
parent.SomeField = 999;
parent.Children.RemoveRange(0, parent.Children.Count);
parent.Children.Add(new Child() { SomeOtherField = "qwe" });
repository.UpdateParent(parent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling

```
db.Children.RemoveRange(parent.Children);
```

should remove the child entities from the database.

Add a method in repository:

```
public void RemoveChildren(IEnumerable<Children> children)
{
   using(var db = new LocalDbContext())
   {
       db.Children.RemoveRange(children);
       db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

And use it:

```
var parent = repository.GetParent(123);
repository.RemoveChildren(parent.Children);
```

Comment: Where in the above code would you put that line of code?

Comment: Maybe good to note that the difference is that `parent.Children.RemoveRange` only cuts the associations, i.e. nullifies foreign keys.

Comment: I probably should have added that I want to update the Parent in one transaction so I don't end up removing the Children without updating the Parent. Adding a new method to my repository wan't really what I had in mind for answer.

Comment: @MathiasR Then you can open the using block with the context above parent.someField = 999, then write db.Children.RemoveRange(children); 
and rewrite your UpdateParent to take a context as a parameter instead of opening a new using there. Below repository.UpdateParent, you should close the using block.

Comment: @MathiasR Another option is to use a single instance of context for a repository, by injecting it in a constructor.

Comment: Yes. Repositories shouldn't use private context instances and they shouldn't execute SaveChanges. An encompassing Unit of Work should do that. (Not to mention the fact that this extra repository layer is an anti pattern anyway).